# Average operation keeps giving "unsupported operand" error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create the average of 5 different variables, each defined and established with "int()", and I keep getting the "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'" error. What does this mean (in simple terms)? I have defined "average" as the average of the list.

```
number_list = [math, english, french, science, edtech]
average = sum(number_list)/5
int(average)
print("Your average mark is ",average,"!")
```

Comment: It means you are trying to add a `int` (integer) to a `str` (string of characters), which makes no sense, like `2 + 'foo'`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like one of the items in your list is a string. And that Python complains that it cannot add that string to the total in the sum function.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell as we can't see the variables you defined. The error simply raise from a string or strings in your variables and they can't be summed up.

If you established your variables just like your average in your code, it won't work. You can check the variable type by `repr()` or `type()`.

```
# string with quote
math = "1"
int(math)
print(repr(math))
print(type(math))
math = int(math)
print(repr(math))
print(type(math))
# integer without quote
english = 2
print(repr(english))
print(type(english))
```

Output:

```
'1'
<class 'str'>
1
<class 'int'>
2
<class 'int'>
```

As you can see the `int(math)` does not turn math to integer, unless you do it by `math = int(math)`, or you should just defined your variable without quote at the first time, so it will be an integer.